# Measuring Stress with Sensors

Tags: data, modeling, strain-gage

I wanted to ask a few questions in the hoped that someone can advise me.

Basically I wish to use a sensor which will be attached to a large piece of fabric, I would then like to use the data from the sensor to inform me about the stress-strain relationship, create and predict models and compare with any existing models.

Any advise, links or research to read into would be incredibly helpful!

Comment: what have you uncovered thru googling. If you say nothing then you need google training rather than EE training

Comment: I have had a look through google and am doing some research but was hoping to get a little professional advise on the sensor aspect and how it will inform the model to help me along

Comment: http://rogers.matse.illinois.edu/files/2012/cpdmsadvfuncmater.pdf

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=fabric+strain+sensor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a resistive strain gauge, a Wheatstone bridge, and an op-amp-based signal conditioning circuit. The values and setup will likely differ depending on the sensor you use, but here's the general circuit:

[image: Signal Conditioning Circuit]

Hopefully this points you in the right direction. Keep searching google and you will find more information.

Comment: I have been told "axial strain sensor" if that helps. We could then use that to feed data to a computer and inform us of the relationship under different environmental conditions etc

Comment: Sorry if I have been a little unclear just looking for any insight

Comment: I see, so you're not trying to interface this with hardware, but software instead. Is this correct? Interfacing a hardware sensor to software is a bit tricky, and probably requires a USB or RS232 interface, which means even more circuitry